# Adding interactivity to a D3 Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, typescript

**BACKGROUND**

I am attempting to build a small library on top of D3 (version 4) where I use only the minimum number of modules necessary to draw a line chart like this:

[image]

**CURRENT STATE**

I suppose you could say I've *succeeded*, it is a crap library, but still. I am able to draw a line chart using only:

```
var chart = new DataChimp.LineChart('.selector').data('apiURL').draw();
```

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/jVPOXG) of the thing in action.

**WHAT NEXT**

I would like to add interactivity so that when a user checks the checkbox, I draw a second line (different colour) on the graph

**WHY**

The learning I get from this, will be used to actually draw a more useful 2nd line (for example the line of averages)

**WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED**

I got this to work with the ugly / hacky method of deleting everything (e.g. grabbing the SVG and removing it from the DOM) and then redrawing the whole thing this time with 2 lines.

I am here to know if there is a better, cleaner way. All my code sits in this public [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Ciwan1859/DataChimp/blob/master/LineChart.ts).

Comment: Have you looked into D3's [data joins](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)? You should think in terms of series. When you have 1 series, you draw 1 line. When you have 2 series, you draw 2 lines, etc.

Comment: @Ashitaka I have now, thank you! I can see their use with data points such as `[{"x": 1.0, "y": 1.1}, {"x": 2.0, "y": 2.5}, …]` but about Line data? That typically looks different. Will my `data` object be an 2 arrays each representing the data for one of the lines?

Comment: The `data()` function should receive an array of arrays `[[{x: 1, y: 1}, ...], [...], ...]` where each inner array contains the data points of a line.